# Can I use kernel parameter printk.time during boot to disable showing timestamps?

Tags: boot, grub2, kernel-parameters

I am trying to use the kernel parameter printk.time in order to prevent showing timestamps in kernel messages logged in dmesg. According to [this](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/admin-guide/kernel-parameters.txt), it's possible to set printk.time=0 to disable the timestamps. So during boot, I interrupt GRUB and modify the kernel line as follows:

[image]

I then resume boot with Ctl+X. After boot is complete I check dmesg and I see that the printk parameter is included, but so are the timestamps:

```
[    0.000000] Command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-4.15.0-60-generic root=UUID=ffd27f69-1382-4328-99fb-fdc7ddca33a5 ro maybe-ubiquity printk.time=0
[    0.000000] Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-4.15.0-60-generic root=UUID=ffd27f69-1382-4328-99fb-fdc7ddca33a5 ro maybe-ubiquity printk.time=0
```